Anchor navigation not working in Flutter when widget is scrolled off-screen
I have the following code for a Flutter widget:
// Dart
import 'dart:convert';
// External libraries
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
// Components
import 'package:pey/components/ui/app_bars/store.dart';
import 'package:pey/components/ui/spinner.dart';
import 'package:pey/components/app/store/section_scroll.dart';
import 'package:pey/components/app/store/section_with_products.dart';
// Utilities
import 'package:pey/utils/graphql_manager.dart';
import 'package:pey/utils/filter_store_sections.dart';
// Types
import 'package:pey/types/store.dart';

class StoreScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? storeId;

  const StoreScreen({super.key, required this.storeId});

  @override
  State<StoreScreen> createState() => _StoreScreenState();
}

class _StoreScreenState extends State<StoreScreen> {
  bool _isLoadingStore = true;
  bool _isLoadingSectionsAndProducts = true;
  List<dynamic> products = [];
  List<dynamic> sections = [];
  Store? store;
  int _selectedSectionIndex = 0;

  // Map to hold GlobalKeys for each section
  final Map<String, GlobalKey> _sectionKeys = {};

  // Initialize ScrollController
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncInitState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> asyncInitState() async {
    try {
      if (widget.storeId == null) {
        throw Exception('Store ID is required');
      }

      // Load store data
      final storeResponse = await Api.getStore(widget.storeId!);
      final storeResponseJson = json.decode(storeResponse.data!);
      store = Store.fromJson(storeResponseJson['getStore']);

      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoadingStore = false;
        });
      }

      // Load sections and products
      final sectionsResponse = await Api.getSectionsByStore(widget.storeId!);
      final sectionsResponseJson = json.decode(sectionsResponse.data!);
      sections = sectionsResponseJson['getSectionsByStore']['items'];

      final productsResponse = await Api.getProductsByStore(widget.storeId!);
      final productsResponseJson = json.decode(productsResponse.data!);
      products = productsResponseJson['getProductsByStore']['items'];

      // Use the utility function to organize sections and products
      sections = filterStoreSections(sections, products);

      // Initialize GlobalKeys for each section
      for (var section in sections) {
        if (_sectionKeys.containsKey(section['id'])) {
          throw Exception('Duplicate section ID found: ${section['id']}');
        }
        _sectionKeys[section['id']] = GlobalKey();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      safePrint('Error getting stores: $e');
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoadingSectionsAndProducts = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void _onSectionTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedSectionIndex = index;
    });

    // Retrieve the section ID based on the index
    final sectionId = sections[index]['id'];
    final key = _sectionKeys[sectionId];

    if (key?.currentContext != null) {
      // Get the RenderBox of the target section
      final RenderBox renderBox =
          key!.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      // Get the position of the target section
      final position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      // Calculate the target scroll offset
      final targetOffset = _scrollController.offset + position.dy - 180;

      _scrollController.animateTo(
        targetOffset,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoadingStore) {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Spinner()),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          ArrowPopAppBar(store: store!, storeId: widget.storeId),
          if (_isLoadingSectionsAndProducts)
            const SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 24),
                    Spinner(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          else ...[
            if (sections.isNotEmpty && sections.length > 1)
              if (sections.isNotEmpty && sections.length > 1)
                StoreSectionScroll(
                  sections: sections,
                  selectedIndex: _selectedSectionIndex,
                  onSectionTap: _onSectionTap,
                ),
            if (products.isEmpty)
              SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const Text('No se encontraron productos'),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () => context.pop(),
                          child: const Text('Volver'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            else
              ...sections.map((section) {
                final sectionProducts = section['id'] == 'otros'
                    ? products
                        .where((product) =>
                            product['sectionId'] == null ||
                            product['sectionId'] == '')
                        .toList()
                    : products
                        .where(
                            (product) => product['sectionId'] == section['id'])
                        .toList();

                return StoreSectionWithProducts(
                  globalKey:
                      _sectionKeys[section['id']], // Assign the GlobalKey
                  title: section['name'],
                  products: sectionProducts,
                );
              }),
            const SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SizedBox(height: 40),
            ),
          ],
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

This creates a screen that looks like this.

It all works well except for the anchor navigation. When you click on the names that appear between the header and the products it automatically scrolls to that section. However, this is causing a problem when a widget has been scrolled off-screen.
The line of code that causes the problem is: if (key?.currentContext != null). The reason key?.currentContext becomes null for off-screen items is that Flutter optimizes rendering by disposing of widgets that are not currently visible. When a widget is scrolled off-screen, its context becomes null until it's rendered again. This causes the anchor navigation to stop working for StoreSectionWithProducts that have already been scrolled.
Any recommendations on how to manage scrolling or ideas on how I could solve this?
